# Prove that the roots of a given polynomial don't have the same absolute value

Tags: polynomials, roots, absolute-value

Let $n \geq 4$ and  $f=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}X^{k}$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients, such that $a_{n}=1,$ $a_{1}\cdot a_{n-1}\neq 0$ and  $|Re(a_{n-1})|>\sqrt[n-2]{\left | \frac{a_{1}}{a_{n-1}} \right |}.$ 
Prove that $f$ does not have all of its roots of the same absolute value.

I haven't done anything meaningful yet.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it correct that $f$ does not have a $X^0$ term? This makes the problem significantly easier.

Comment: My mistake, the polynomial has an $X^0$ term.

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

Let $n=4$ and consider $f(x)=x(x-1)^2(x-2)=x^4-4x^3+5x^2-2x$. All hypotheses hold:

- $a_n=1$
- $a_{n-1}=-4$ and $a_1=-2$, so their product is nonzero
- $|\Re(a_{n-1})|=4 > \sqrt{\left|\frac{a_1}{a_{n-1}}\right|}=\frac{\sqrt2}2$

By construction, $f$ has a double root $1$, so it is a counter-example.

Comment: But that's not false! We have to prove that there exist two roots with distinct modulus, which is true from your solution.

Comment: What if $f(x)=(x-1)^4=x^4-4x^3+6x^2-4x+1$? All hypotheses hold: $n=4$, $a_n=1$, $a_{n-1}=a_1=-4$ (so their product is nonzero) and $|\Re(a_{n-1})|=4 > \sqrt{\left|\frac{a_1}{a_{n-1}}\right|}=1$. By construction, all of $f$'s roots have the same modulus.